# In MS Lists, is there a way to show the most recent update to a column where 'append changes to existing text' is enabled?

Tags: json, list, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online

I've built a new Outstanding Issues Tracker for our team using MS Lists (as an app/tab in a Teams channel), and it includes a column called 'Updates' where people can provide the latest news/actions on their items.  I've enabled both 'Rich Text' and, most importantly, 'append changes to existing text'--this captures the name of the person making the update and the time they added it.  Very useful.

However...the way it shows up in MS Lists is simply 'View Entries'--you have to click on an item (record/row) to actually view the text.  That's fine, but I wonder if there's a way to add **another** column that would show the date of the most recent update in the Updates column.  That way I could hone in on the items that have been updated most recently--or chase up the ones that have been languishing.

Does anyone know if it's possible to do this?  Have googled about to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently It is not possible to show the date of the most recent update in update column. Each template in List comes with a predefined list structure.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/list-templates-in-microsoft-365-62f0e4cf-d55d-4f89-906f-4a34e036ded1

Currently here we can displayed only Reported Date.

Could you please raise a user voice here for new feature requirement:
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new

[image]